# Macintosh System 6 on Quadra?

Tags: apple-macintosh, apple, mac-os-classic, motorola-68000, m68k

System 6 is not officially supported on 68040 Macintoshes, but has anyone successfully run System 6 on an early Quadra, e.g. the Quadra 700?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quadra 700's had a ROM-version which was 32-bit-clean (not using one byte out of all 32-bit-addresses anymore to allow addressing of more than 16MB RAM). Therefore it is quite unlikely, that anyone succeeded in running any System 6.x on a Quadra 700 computer. At least this version of System 6 needs to bring its own 24-bit-memory manager in RAM with it.

Just be curious: why is System 7.0.1 no option for you?

Comment: Insightful comment about the memory manager needing to be patched, at the very least. So this does not sound easily possible.

I'm trying to create some software and put it on a disk which will boot any 68k Macintosh (except for the original 64k rom machines), including 68040 Quadras. I wanted to put the System 6 system file on the disk along with the application, but I guess I will have to go with System 7.

Comment: @ZaneKaminski - some of the PowerBooks are *really* picky about boot systems and might not start with generic disks

Comment: System 7 can be booted by a MacPlus or later so almost any classic Mac can run it. In fact something like 7.1 can boot on everything up through the 840AV (given the right enablers).